# Able to copy stringstreams using rdbuf(), but not fstreams for some reason?

Tags: c++, stream, fstream, stringstream

EDIT: My use of the word "content" below is pretty misleading. The difference implied between `somestringstream.rdbuf()` and `somefstream.rdbuf()` doesn't exist (just thought so due to misunderstanding visual studio debugging information).

---

IIUC `rdbuf()` apparently returns a pointer to the beginning of the streams content. So using two `stringstreams` this works:

```
b << a.rdbuf();  //b is stringstream, a is stringstream
```

Both a and b now have the content of a.
But when a is a `fstream` and b a `stringstream` this doesn't seem to work in the same way:

```
b << a.rdbuf();  //b is stringstream, a is fstream
```

Now b has the content of a, but a doesn't have any content anymore. How can i make sure that a keeps its content when a is a `fstream` and why does this work with `stringstream`, but not with `fstream`?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Full (tested) code with examples:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string texteins;
    stringstream a, b;
    texteins = "just some test";
    a << texteins;
    b << a.rdbuf();
    // a = "just some test"
    // b = "just some test"

    a << "more words";
    // a = "just some testmore words"
    // b = "just some test"


    stringstream c;
    fstream inFile("justsomeexample.txt", ios::in); //justsomeexample.txt = "aline\nanother line\nsome words in a line"
    c << inFile.rdbuf();
    // inFile = "";     //Why is this empty, but stringstream above not?
    // c =  "aline\nanother line\nsome words in a line"


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course it still has content, but the read position is at the end of the file. Reset the file stream to the beginning of the file. Using `rdbuf()` here is equivalent to using a loop to read from the file stream, a character at a time. What do you think happens when the entire file gets read?

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense. (I didn't directly see the content of fstream in visual studio (unlike for the stringstreams) and so instead used getline, which automatically starts at the current read position (and yes i dont know a lot about streams^^).